# VB.Net TreeView filtering Parent and Child Records

Tags: vb.net, treeview, vb.net-2010

What is wrong with this code? I have 3 tables, Building related to VisitorSheet, and visitorsheet related to Visit. However not all Buildings have VisitorSheet and not all VisitorSheet has Visits. When this code is run all VisitorSheets are displayed for each Building and all Visits are displayed for each VisitorSheet. How do I filter to have the correct records displayed in each Treeview node?

```
Me.VisitTableAdapter.Fill(Me.VisitDbDataSet.Visit)
Me.VisitorSheetTableAdapter.Fill(Me.VisitorSheetDbDataSet.VisitorSheet)
Me.BuildingTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BuildingDbDataSet.Building)

Try
    For Each masterRow As DataRow In BuildingDbDataSet.Tables("Building").Rows
        Dim masterNode As New TreeNode(masterRow("Abbr").ToString())
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(masterNode)

        For Each childRow As DataRow In VisitorSheetDbDataSet.Tables("VisitorSheet").Rows
            masterRow.GetChildRows("SheetNo")

            Dim childNode As New TreeNode(childRow("SheetDate").ToString())
            masterNode.Nodes.Add(childNode)

            For Each childRow1 As DataRow In VisitDbDataSet.Tables("Visit").Rows
                masterRow.GetChildRows("VisitNo")

                Dim childNode1 As New TreeNode(childRow1("Visitor").ToString())
                childNode.Nodes.Add(childNode1)
            Next
        Next
    Next
```

Sample

[image: enter code here]

Answer (score 0):

You're currently iterating over all rows in each table. You need to iterate over the child rows only.

```
For Each masterRow As DataRow In BuildingDbDataSet.Tables("Building").Rows
    Dim masterNode As New TreeNode(masterRow("Abbr").ToString())
    TreeView1.Nodes.Add(masterNode)

    For Each childRow As DataRow In VisitorSheetDbDataSet.Tables("VisitorSheet").Rows
        'masterRow.GetChildRows("SheetNo")

        Dim childNode As New TreeNode(childRow("SheetDate").ToString())
        masterNode.Nodes.Add(childNode)

        For Each childRow1 As DataRow In masterRow.GetChildRows("SheetNo")

            '...

        Next
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Now 4:54 Am - 11/22/2016. Tried various changes but still stumped. Grateful if you may insert changes to code which would allow me to complete program. All other aspect of program are OK except code for Loading TREEVIEW. Going to have some rest.